# Paypal form select

Tags: paypal

I'm confounded why this won't work - the first select works, the second one doesn't. The first one though, does not provide any textual info about the selection.

```
<form action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>  
<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>  
<input type='hidden' name='business' value='payments@site.com'>
<select name='os0'>
<option value='25€ Individual'>Individual rate - 25&euro;</option>
<option value='75€ Group'>Agency rate - 75&euro;</option>
</select> 
<input type='hidden' name='option_index' value='0'>
<input type='hidden' name='option_select0' value='25€ Individual'>
<input type='hidden' name='option_amount0' value='25.00'>
<input type='hidden' name='option_select1' value='75€ Group'>
<input type='hidden' name='option_amount1' value='75.00'>
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='EUR'>  
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.site.com/backtoyou/'>   
<input type='submit' value='Pay with PayPal!'>  
<img alt='' border='0' src='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif' width='1' height='1'>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? What do you mean by "first select" and "second select"? I see one `<select>...</select>`.

Comment: The first one sends the info to Paypal and works. The second one, Paypal gives me an error saying something is wrong. Sorry I wasn't more clear.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit lost. The first *what*? I see only one submit button, so I'm not sure what's going where here. You'll need to provide us with all the info you can!